# /etc directory causes boot errors

Tags: linux, debian

Long story short. My /etc directory has been deleted. I have a complete copy of it in a different directory on my machine. The issue is before I realized it was deleted my machine was restarted. Now I am unable to boot into my machine or even rescue mode. On rescue mode it gets hung on the message "2 urandom warnings missed due to ratelimiting". I'm assuming this is because the /etc directory is missing. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: boot from a live distro, and copy the files back?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Looks like this is the only option i have left. Do you have any links to documents/videos that show this process as I've never actually had to boot from a live CD.

Comment: well, for a PC or server with a bootable optical disk, you just put in the CD and reboot. you may need to make sure the bios is set to boot from the optical drive, or use F8 to select the boot device during POST. it can be a bit of a pain sometimes, but shouldn't be too difficult. Once you have it booting from the right source, the liveCD will boot up and sign you into a desktop automatically. then mount your disks, and you should be ready to go.

Comment: Ok awesome. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/etc` folder in any Linux/Posix system contains the complete
system configuration
including basically everything from hardware driver+network config to application software config.

Many files here are auto-generated at OS or application software
installation time.
Without it and without a backup there is no chance to repair your Linux.

If you don't have a backup *from your computer*, you can still
recover the files in `/home/` by booting from a live CD/DVD
and save your data. Then you can reinstall.

Some references that can get you started for creating a live CD/DVD:

- [How to Create a Live Ubuntu USB Drive With Persistent Storage](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/)
- [How to Create a Bootable Linux USB Flash Drive, the Easy Way](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/)

Comment: Thanks for you response. Reading around looks like this is the only option left. Do you have any links to a video or document explaining the boot from live CD process as I've don't have much experience with this process.

Comment: There are many resources that you can google. I added two random ones, but there are many more.

Comment: I'll take a look at these links. I appreciate all the help.